# How force rollback transaction entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing

How can I force rollback the SaveChanges() method even if it succeeds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wrap it into a [transaction scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx), and then dispose of it without completing the scope.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeOption.Required, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue ))
{
  /* your code goes here */
}
```

If you want to actually save the changes call `scope.Complete()`

See this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose.aspx) for more information.

Comment: will TrasactionScope delete data from the database after doing save changes ?

Comment: Any regular transaction would do as well.

Comment: It will do a rollback, so the data wont be saved, but if you have autoincrementing Id's they will be incremented.

Comment: can i query the database to test before the rollback using linq to entities ?

Comment: As long as it's all contained in the same scope, yes (in my example, everything exists in the using statement) You can query the db, and it will return the updated data. Once the scope gets disposed everything gets rolled back.

Comment: If multiple user add info at same time, I have any chance to rollback another user information?